# Does anyone know a good reading resource about the history/formulation of quantum physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, history

I'm looking for a reading resource that reviews the experimental observations, and subsequent physical models that lead to the formulation of quantum physics. For example the experimental observations of Black body radiation can be explained by Planck's law, which requires quantised energy. I want to know why these experimental observations required quantum physics. The reading source would preferably show the mathematical derivations of the models and how the theory was developed in chronological order.

Comment: See also https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try Quantum Physics of Atoms, Molecules, Solids, Nuclei, and Particles by Eisberg. He provides a good introduction to the early models o black body radiation.

Comment: This question belongs to [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com). You are likely to get better answers there. There are ***scores*** of sourcebooks of the type you are seeking.

Comment: Wikipedia has a page on [the history of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_quantum_mechanics) which has many references listed.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend: "Thirty Years that Shook Physics: The Story of Quantum Theory" by George Gamow. It is quite well regarded and IMO it does a very nice tightrope between an entertaining bio and a textbook.

It really does fit exactly what you are looking for in your question.

There aren't really "equations" in the book, however the actual concepts are very nicely explained and easy to understand. You won't need to bring out your pad and pencil to solve anything. However you will still learn a LOT about the fundamentals of quantum physics(pun intended), as well how it evolved to the standard model from essentially the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the level of mathematics you are comfortable with. The "no-math standard" was for many years a book called *30 Years That Shook Physics* by George Gamow.

Answer (score 0):

Inward Bound, by Abraham Pais, is about exactly what you seem to be looking for.